# Why Unit Tests Assertion fail on Gradle 5.1, but passes on 1.12, both use same Java version 1.8?

Tags: java, gradle, junit

I have a multi-module project which is using

- Java 1.8
- JUnit 4.12
- Gradle

When compiling a single module, its unit tests are failing on asserting null with Gradle 5.1, but same tests pass on Gradle 1.12 and module compiles successfully. Not changing anything except what is deprecated in 5.1. I can't understand why same framework fails on a recent Gradle version.

One test fails on JUunit `Assert.assertNotNull()`, which is checking for a string is null or not.

A second test fails on JUnit `Assert.assertTrue()`.

`build.gradle` is same in both except configuration name changes and I have confirmed all dependencies are downloaded and compiling.

Can't share build script, but if you don't understand something I'll try to make a pseudo script.

I thought assertion errors were more related to language version than tools?

```java
public class Test {
    private String property;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        property = Singleton.getInstance().getProperty();
    }

// test failure 1

    @Test
    public void shouldAbleToGetProperty() {
        assertNotNull(property);
    }

// test failure 2

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnTrueIfPropertyIsTrue() {
        Assert.assertTrue(Singleton.getInstance().isTrue());
    }
}
```

`Singleton` class is a normal singleton which reads property files in resources folder.

**NOT ACTUAL CODE**

```java
class Singleton {

    private Map<String, Properties> properties;

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        // return singleton as its meant to be ...
        // read property file from project and hold it in map.
    }
}
```

Comment: A [mre] should have enough code that we can compile and run it ourselves. Could you make it runnable and verify that your MRE has the bug in question? It shouldn't just demonstrate a concept; it should *actually fail* if we run it with the Java/JUnit/Gradle versions you're using.

Comment: I can't put much code as its a bit complex, but I'll try to update the question and try to describe it

Comment: I **strongly** recommend you post actual runnable code, not a description. A description will almost certainly omit a crucial detail. It may take several hours to create an MRE, but it'd be time well spent. There's a good chance the very process of figuring out what code is relevant will help you pinpoint the problem.

Comment: thanks, while I can't post actual code I'll try looking at it, but the thing I want to know more about is does upgrading gradle actually affects tests? As I think they should be relevant to language implementation

Comment: I have different branches which hold different gradle versions, ran the build in one with same code and gradle 1.12, project is running on this version in pipelines.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209003/discussion-between-ateebahmed-and-john-kugelman).

Comment: One way to create an MRE is to take your failing program and strip out code, classes, classpath JARs, etc., and verify that the problem is still reproducible at each step. See how small you can get the program. Alternatively, start a new program from scratch and write the least amount of code to reproduce the failure. Or if you have to, try both approaches and meet in the middle, like the intercontinental railroad.